# Selenium WebDriver and InternetExplorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've recently updated to Selenium 2.24.1 to get Firefox 13 working.  With this update you are now to run an executable similar to chromedriver.exe for it to dispatch events to IE.  However I have had no luck in getting tests to run with IE.  For this to run with chrome I obviously have to set the webdriver.chrome.driver bit as well, but things work fine in it and Firefox with the same code.

Here is my source code:

```
public class GoogleTest {

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
  final WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("test");
  driver.findElement(By.name("q")).submit();
  driver.quit();
}
```

}

However I am greeted with this stack trace upon execution of this test

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with name == q (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 395 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 15:28:49'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_01'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: e20f8370-00ed-4bf6-a4fa-a0c09c2b6d8c
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:472)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:303)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:291)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:234)
```

Comment: This exact code works for me well on IE8 and Windows XP SP3 32-bit. Which IE and/or OS are you on? Are you _absolutely_ sure you are using the newest IEDriverServer.exe and not the old one? Does it open the google page?

Comment: I'm on IE9 Windows 7.  I pulled from the downloads section only yesterday.  I've tried both the 64 bit and the 32 bit versions of IEDriverServer.  The Google page is opened just fine, but as soon as I attempt to interact with the driver it's like the information is never dispatched to the driver.

Comment: Okay. Does ANYTHING else work? Say typing into a form on a local html page containing a single input? Or ... well, anything?

Comment: Hmm, now we are getting somewhere.  If I use my sample toy webapp locally, I'm able to interact with things, but as soon as I reach out for an external site, things fail (even though the page loads).

Comment: @Slanec can you tell me what the IEDriverServer is good for? i run tests with the selenium-standalone-server and it works as it worked always

Comment: Odd, if I test this within [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/jobs/1c94a061ebad4758830029097020149e) I get the same element not found exceptions, but my test still finishes.

Comment: IEDriverServer.exe had been (and still is) bundled in the package in the form of .dll file. However, Selenium developers have recently made a decision to take it out of the package and serve it separately (one of the reasons for it being that antivirus sw didn't like .dll files in .jar packages). They will eventually remove it from the package in a future version - now we're in the transition phase when both approaches work.

Comment: The Sauce Labs test works as expected, just the Error messages are weird. But notice that the "failed" ones are with a location strategy = "id", not name. So, when searching by name, it tries to find by an id (which failed and was reported - weird, but true) and then by name which was ok.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a antivirus or firewall software blocking ... something, but that would be just strange.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is probably really obvious, but as you didn't mention it in your original post and you just downloaded the driver and your internal toy app is working, have you double-checked the security settings in IE as mentioned on the IEDriver code page:

> On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".

If you were using a previous version of Selenium before, you've likely already done this, but I figured it was worth checking just to be sure...

Comment: Last set of updates decided to bork these settings, and the INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS did nothing either.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this step (using a different Windows VM than originally). I was in debug mode and webdriver couldn't find anything, can't print page source, all it could do was open the page. I was stumped. Thanks again!

Comment: This is not work for me In IE8 browser. I enable and disable "Enable Protected Mode" then try but I am still getting error in the eclipse 

please check my code http://pastebin.com/TBxhptUB

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message is misleading at least it was in my case. I had a system that was locked down by system administrator with Protected Mode: Off. So I wasn't able to switch the Protected mode. Then I realized that the system had an admin user, so logged in as admin user and tried to switch the Protected Mode. It was still disabled. Then I run Selenium under the admin user account and things worked just fine.

So you may need to login with admin privileges to be able to run selenium. That trick worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\workspace\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the IEWebdriver server that you downloaded. If you are using 32bit IE, download and use the 32bit IEWebdriver.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having very similar issues. There was a setting in Internet Options that needed to be turned on in order to make it work. Advanced > Settings > Security > Allow active content to run in files on My Computer.

Once I checked this box, my IE tests worked as expected and could find elements and interact with the browser.